# Summarizing articles with ChatGPT

Tags: natural-language-processing, open-ai, chatgpt

You cannot upload files such as articles on ChatGPT. As an alternative I provided links to ChatGPT of the corresponding webpages but it is clear from its summaries that it is not able to open the link and is not actually summarizing that article. Similarly, telling it the title of the article and author doesn't work because it does not access the article. For example, if you give it the prompt "Write the 4th paragraph of this article: https://www.msn.com/en-ca/news/canada/this-ontario-teacher-wants-schools-to-be-more-open-to-muslim-student-needs-starting-with-prayer/ar-AA19wzbe?ocid=hpmsn&cvid=b735bc2290e14ee385647759d7de753f&ei=11 " it will not write the correct paragraph so I am not sure how it summarizes the article. On the other hand, you need to pay to access some articles so I find it unclear how it summarizes those articles. Also, the articles can be long so if you paste sections in separate chunks ChatGPT will summarize each section, which is not ideal because it should summarize the whole article at the same time.

How do you summarize articles with ChatGPT?

Comment: I usually copy paste the whole article and ask him to summarize . it works for me .

Comment: Although, you can't trust it to not make something up in the process.

Answer (score -3):

This prompt worked for me with [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/).

```
Can you summarise this
https://www.msn.com/en-ca/news/canada/this-ontario-teacher-wants-schools-to-be-more-open-to-muslim-student-needs-starting-with-prayer/ar-AA19wzbe?ocid=hpmsn&cvid=b735bc2290e14ee385647759d7de753f&ei=11
```

If you want a more elaborate summary. Use the prompt

```
Can you elaborate?
```

Note: I have not verified the correctness of the summary.

Comment: you should verify the correctness because it's not able to actually read the article